# how to generate auto incremental item code in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, codeigniter-3

I wanna create a column in database that will increment the item code with prefix say IT with respect to the primary key (id). can anybody suggest easy way to do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: So prefix `IT` for every row?

Comment: yes. column name would be item_code and in every row item code should look like i.e IT0001, IT0002, IT0003 so on.

Comment: i'm trying to do it in same table not with two tables. is there anyway to do it within same table?

Comment: Well, instead of storing the prefix, why not attach it only while displaying?

Comment: You are right. I need to store this because when i'm generating barcodes i will retrieve it from db when searching for items and print their barcode labels. i'm doing this for first time so i could be wrong so i'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Then just fetch the ID and generate the barcode by passing it into your function like `generate_barcode('IT'.$your_id);`

Comment: Store as less as possible in the database. Numbers are much way faster as IDs. Just prefix on display.